# Why is my function not working everytime I open the screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo, use-effect

I want to check if there is a stored value connected to 'amazonAddressKey' everytime I open the screen but it's not working always.

```
 const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    saveAmazonVisibility();
  }, []);

  const [amazonVisibility, setAmazonVisibility] = React.useState();
  async function saveAmazonVisibility() {
    const amazonGetKey = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("amazonAddressKey");
    if (JSON.parse(amazonGetKey)) {
      setAmazonVisibility(true);
      console.log(JSON.parse(amazonGetKey));
    } else {
      setAmazonVisibility(false);
      console.log(JSON.parse(amazonGetKey));
    }
    setIsLoaded(true);
  }
```

Comment: When you say 'it is not working', what exactly is 'it'

Comment: This is most likely that you are using react-navigation and you expect the component to be mounted everytime. If so, you have to use a `focus` listener to run your function.

Comment: Thank you @IanVasco ! That's what I was looking for. I was thinking that the useEffect() is doing that job.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "useFocusEffect", so you can call a function every time your page is focus, here an example:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action
     saveAmazonVisibility();
    });

    // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```

You can read about this hook here:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/